# how to wait for await in async method to finish the all the executions?

Tags: c#, async-await

For the following code im calling that async void method.

```
  public  void LoadSystemDetails(int clientId)
    {
        DataSystem.Name = "Salesforce System";
        DataSystem.Description = "";
        GetAllFields(clientId);
    }
```

following code is `GetAllFields` method

```
 public async void GetAllFields(int clientId)
    {
        this.DataSystem.SystemTables = new List<DataSystemTable>();


        using (var forceClient = await ConnectToSalesforceByOAuth(clientId))
        {
              var SalesForceTable = new DataSystemTable
            {
                TableName = "Contact"
            };
            DataSystem.SystemTables.Add(SalesForceTable);

            var contact = forceClient.DescribeAsync<SalesforceObject>("Contact");
            var tableFields = new List<DataSystemField>();

            foreach (var con in contact.Result.Fields)
            {
                tableFields.Add(new DataSystemField
                {

                    ColumnName = con.Name,

                });
            }

            SalesForceTable.EissSyncSystemFields = tableFields;
      }
```

and i call `callbackScript` as below.

```
  callbackScript.AppendLine(string.Format("var destinationSystem ={0};", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.DestinationSystem, Formatting.Indented)));
```

here `DestinationSystem` is calling the `LoadSystemDetails`. Like `DestinationSystem.LoadSystemDetails(clientId)`

while `using (var forceClient = await ConnectToSalesforceByOAuth(clientId))` line is execute at the time the `callbackScript`  is executed. so the `SystemTables` doesn't have any value. but it having `Name` and `Description`.

so here i need to wait the `LoadSystemDetails` to finish the `GetAllFields`.

How i do that.Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need `LoadSystemDetails` to wait for `GetAllFields`, there are 2 problems here:

- you are calling async method from a synchronous context
- `GetAllFields` is async void, which means fire and forget. You will never be able to wait for it to finish.

Solution:
First, NEVER use `async void` if you need to wait for the result or end. Use `async Task` instead
Second, either convert `LoadSystemDetails` to async method also, then await the GetAllFields (that should return `Task`), or use `GetAllFields(clientId).Wait()`

take a look at this article for more information on async/await: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As @netchkin already said: Never use `async void`. Use `async Task`. You don't have to return a `Task` yourself, you can still use `return;`